# Solving an ODE system with non-linearity

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

**Question:** How could we solve this ODE system
$$u'=\alpha(1-x)-(\alpha+\beta)u, \quad u(0)=u_0 $$
$$v'=\gamma x-(\gamma+\delta)v,\quad v(0)=v_0 $$
$$x'=\delta v(1-x)-\beta ux, \quad x(0)=x_0 $$
Here, $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta>0$ and we can assume that $\alpha\ll \beta, \gamma\ll \delta$?

**My attempt**:The equilibria are $(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta},0,0)$ and $(0,\frac{\gamma}{\gamma+\delta},1)$. I would like to find explicit solutions or good approximations. Numerically, $u(t),v(t),x(t)$ look like logistic functions.
[image: Plot]

The best I came up with, is the approximation
$$u\approx\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}(1-x),\quad v\approx\frac{\gamma}{\gamma+\delta} x$$
when $u$ and $v$ are small compared to $x$ and hence their derivatives $\dot{u}\approx 0,\dot{v}\approx 0$. This implies
$$\dot{x}=\underbrace{\left(\frac{\gamma\delta}{\gamma+\delta}-\frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha+\beta}\right)}_{\equiv c}x(1-x)$$
so
$$x(t)=\frac{x_0e^{ct}}{1+x_0(e^{ct}-1)},\quad u(t)= \frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}(1-x(t)),\quad v(t)=\frac{\gamma}{\gamma+\delta} x(t)$$
**Problem:** While the limiting behavior of the approximation is the same as the exact solution, at intermediate times there is a substantial discrepancy. So I'm seeking better approximations or even an exact solution.

**Any help or comment is greatly appreciated!**

Comment: Would you also be interested in the partial result with the restriction $\gamma+\delta=\alpha+\beta$?

Comment: Yes, I think this could give valuable insights!