# A simple question about $b(x)\cdot \nabla u(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, characteristics, linear-pde

I want to find solutions $u$ to the equation
$$b(x,y,z)\cdot\nabla u(x,y,z)=0\quad (x,y,z)\in D$$
$$u(1,0,z)=1,\, u(0,y,0)=0$$
where $D$ is the domain (a simplex) defined by
$$D=\{(x,y,z)\in[0,1]^3: 0\leq x+y\leq 1,\quad 0\leq z\leq x\}$$
The vector field $b$ is given by
$$b(x,y,z)=\begin{pmatrix}\delta z(1-x)-\beta xy\\\alpha(1-x)-(\alpha+\beta)y\\\gamma x-(\gamma+\delta)z\end{pmatrix}$$
where $0<\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta<1$ are constants.
Using the method of characteristic, one has to solve the system
$$(\dot{x}(s),\dot{y}(s),\dot{z}(s))^T=b(x(s),y(s),z(s))$$
which was the content of my [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4881335/solving-an-ode-system-with-non-linearity). This system has two fixed points $(0,\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta},0)$ and $(1,0,\frac{\gamma}{\gamma+\delta})$. Any interesting solution of this ODE system can be extended to move from one fixed point to the other. Now the method of characteristics would give $\dot{u}(x(s),y(s),z(s))=0$, so $u$ is constant along characteristic curves.

**Questions:** This seems to contradict the boundary conditions. Can we conclude that this equation has no (continuous) solution? Or does this simply mean that characteristics don't start and end at the parts of the boundary where $u$ is given? Do I need to find conditions on other parts of the boundary or is there another way to solve this equation?
I'm sorry if this is kind of vague, but I never encountered such a problem before.

**Any help or comment is greatly appreciated!**

Comment: "This seems to contradict the boundary conditions" Only if there is a characteristic that goes from a point $(1,0,z)$ to a point $(0,y,0)$. In this case any characteristic that stars at a point $(0,y_*,0)$ will move along the line $(0,y,0)$ (towards the fixpoint) and likewise for the other line. Thus the boundary lines are in fact characteristics themselves so there is no contraction as far as I can see.

Comment: Actually, thinking a bit more about it you might be able to use some kind of argument like this to conclude. The fixpoint at $x=0$ looks like an attractor and that at $x=1$ looks like it repels so I guess if you study the evolution of a characteristic from within the simplex it will like turn out to go towards the fixpoint at $x=0$ implying that the function is constant within the simplex. Turning this into a proof probably requires a bit more work, but it looks like it could work.

Comment: @Winther Sorry for the delay, but I've tried to plot the problem in Python. You seem to be right, every point in the simplex tends to a fixed point, thus its value is either 1 or 0. Thank you very much for your time and effort!